# Checking Quantity from API on checkout

Tags: magento2

I get my products from external API and send them to Magento, the problem is, the quantity is not synced with the API, so I want to update the quantity after the user click on place older.

I don't know where to start, I know theres observers but I never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

to create an observer in Magento, you will need to create a module: once you have your module in place,

you may add an event observer creating an events.xml file in your etc module folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_success">
    <observer name="mbs_order_save_after" instance="Mbs\Module\Observer\OrderSaveAfter" />
</event>
</config>
```

then, you need the observer class added in your module:

```
class OrderSaveAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
   /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getParentItem()) continue;

                /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
                $product = $item->getProduct();

                if (!is_null($product->getSku())) {
                    // put your code calling your API here
                    // or also, update the product quantity in Magento system at this point
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Log details of this exception
            //Mage::log($e->getMessage(), Zend_Log::ERR);
        }
    }
}
```

I imagine if you are new,  you may ask yourself how to write the code to perform product update. Also, you could do with explanations on how product stock update work with the framework. Hopefully, this small input will give you some pointers.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did some research to use Magento Core API, So I know how to update the stock but I just needed to update in checkout event, thank you so much I will test it